# CSS for variable height with minimum and maximum limits

Tags: css

I have an image in the left sidebar widget. Width is 100%. Is it possible to change the height of the image automatically according to the length of the post? I want the minimum height to be 450px, max 1000px, with automatic adjustment in between this range. What CSS tags should be added?

```
 <div id="HTML5" class='widget HTML">

 <div class="widget content">
```

And:

```
<img src='https://abcd' style='width:100%; height:???; border:none;
margin-bottom: 5px; padding:3px'/>
```

Comment: Thanks Harsh for suggesting this edit.

Comment: If you're going to basically undo someone's edit (the addition of the "the" doesn't count), *don't approve the edit*, much less thank them. You are only going to send the wrong message.

Comment: You should post the minimum code you have so far to make it clearer what you want to happen.

Comment: I have provided sufficient information.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, I suggest to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), setting min-height and max-width to your image, it will make it dependent of its parent the sidebar, in your side bar you can put your limits 400px and 1000px;

```css
.container{
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
.content{
  display:inline-block;
  width:60%;
}
.sidebar {
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align:top;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 39%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:450px;
    max-height:1000px;
}
.sidebar img
{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <main class='content'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sagittis, ante vitae sagittis mattis, dui turpis rutrum odio, eget varius diam ligula lobortis metus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed orci odio, ultrices nec ipsum a, ultricies vestibulum metus. Proin suscipit rhoncus libero ac fermentum. Fusce non dolor non dui tincidunt iaculis et ut diam. Aenean semper massa libero, eget maximus dolor sodales at. Nullam maximus sollicitudin nunc sit amet faucibus. Integer lorem erat, cursus ut odio in, convallis vehicula dui. Cras maximus facilisis lorem, ac sodales leo vulputate ac. Quisque mattis ante non sem euismod fringilla. Ut neque magna, interdum eu mattis et, malesuada rhoncus est. Duis odio dui, viverra mattis arcu et, laoreet tincidunt mauris. Cras scelerisque quam quis euismod lobortis.

Nullam aliquam diam nunc, et finibus mi gravida in. Nam et diam vel leo lobortis lobortis ut in metus. Integer vitae vehicula nulla. Ut ex risus, bibendum vitae urna ut, cursus luctus mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse eget arcu justo. Ut id congue enim. Donec nunc ex, rhoncus sit amet rhoncus a, dictum at lacus. Morbi lorem eros, accumsan non nulla nec, viverra ullamcorper libero. Duis non ex elit. Maecenas sapien eros, volutpat quis lorem consectetur, laoreet feugiat nulla.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sagittis, ante vitae sagittis mattis, dui turpis rutrum odio, eget varius diam ligula lobortis metus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed orci odio, ultrices nec ipsum a, ultricies vestibulum metus. Proin suscipit rhoncus libero ac fermentum. Fusce non dolor non dui tincidunt iaculis et ut diam. Aenean semper massa libero, eget maximus dolor sodales at. Nullam maximus sollicitudin nunc sit amet faucibus. Integer lorem erat, cursus ut odio in, convallis vehicula dui. Cras maximus facilisis lorem, ac sodales leo vulputate ac. Quisque mattis ante non sem euismod fringilla. Ut neque magna, interdum eu mattis et, malesuada rhoncus est. Duis odio dui, viverra mattis arcu et, laoreet tincidunt mauris. Cras scelerisque quam quis euismod lobortis.

Nullam aliquam diam nunc, et finibus mi gravida in. Nam et diam vel leo lobortis lobortis ut in metus. Integer vitae vehicula nulla. Ut ex risus, bibendum vitae urna ut, cursus luctus mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse eget arcu justo. Ut id congue enim. Donec nunc ex, rhoncus sit amet rhoncus a, dictum at lacus. Morbi lorem eros, accumsan non nulla nec, viverra ullamcorper libero. Duis non ex elit. Maecenas sapien eros, volutpat quis lorem consectetur, laoreet feugiat nulla.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sagittis, ante vitae sagittis mattis, dui turpis rutrum odio, eget varius diam ligula lobortis metus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed orci odio, ultrices nec ipsum a, ultricies vestibulum metus. Proin suscipit rhoncus libero ac fermentum. Fusce non dolor non dui tincidunt iaculis et ut diam. Aenean semper massa libero, eget maximus dolor sodales at. Nullam maximus sollicitudin nunc sit amet faucibus. Integer lorem erat, cursus ut odio in, convallis vehicula dui. Cras maximus facilisis lorem, ac sodales leo vulputate ac. Quisque mattis ante non sem euismod fringilla. Ut neque magna, interdum eu mattis et, malesuada rhoncus est. Duis odio dui, viverra mattis arcu et, laoreet tincidunt mauris. Cras scelerisque quam quis euismod lobortis.

Nullam aliquam diam nunc, et finibus mi gravida in. Nam et diam vel leo lobortis lobortis ut in metus. Integer vitae vehicula nulla. Ut ex risus, bibendum vitae urna ut, cursus luctus mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse eget arcu justo. Ut id congue enim. Donec nunc ex, rhoncus sit amet rhoncus a, dictum at lacus. Morbi lorem eros, accumsan non nulla nec, viverra ullamcorper libero. Duis non ex elit. Maecenas sapien eros, volutpat quis lorem consectetur, laoreet feugiat nulla.
  </main>
  <aside class="sidebar">
      <img  src="http://placehold.it/100x1000" />
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: RenzoCC, I have made an addition to my query a bit to make it more clear. Can you just go over it and modify your answer?

Comment: Should I use .sidebar-left to be more specific? And #HTML5 in place of. container? Because this code does not mention that the side-bar is on left and container Id is #HTML5.

Comment: There should be no text in the container, only the image.

Answer (score 0):

When I need responsiveness with images, I never use the **img** tag. Instead using css, you have a lot more control with **background-image, background-size and background-position**.

The key is background-size. From the docs:

> **cover:**    Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that
>   the background area is completely covered by the background image.
>   Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the
>   background positioning area
>
> **contain:**  Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width
>   and its height can fit inside the content area

Here is a demo showing this :

**EDIT:** Updated the demo to use **flexbox** to control the height of the sidebar and post (on the right).

```js
function init() {
  $('.post').text('blah blah');
}

function generatePost(isLong) {
  var text = [];
  var length = isLong ? 1000 : 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) text.push('blah');

  $('.post').text(text.join(' '));
}

$(function() {
  init();
})
```

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/76/22/5b/76225b3c2d672b5ddb6afc0bc5724488--rainy-days-rainy-weather.jpg');
  width: 125px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.main {
  width: 400px;
  max-height: 700px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.sidebar.tall {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="generatePost()">Generate Post</button>
<button onclick="generatePost(true)">Generate Long Post</button>

<div class="page">
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <p class="post">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flyer, I have made an addition to my query a bit to make it more clear. Can you just go over it and modify your answer?

Comment: I'm not clear on the goal. The image is in a sidebar yet it's 100% wide? I'm not getting that part. Is it a background image to show beneath the post? And what kind of post are we talking about, a list of posted comments? Is there a website or image you can provide to state the goal?

Comment: No, No. The width of the left sidebar is 125px. It has nothing to do with the main post which is in the middle. The left sidebar will have a widget which would contain an image. If the post is 555px in height, so the image container (HTML% in this case) should be. If the post is 900px in length, the image container should adjust its height accordingly. In any case, the image height should also change with changing container's height. We can keep image height 100% which will fill the container. Only the problem is, how to adjust height of the container automatically.

Comment: I see so it's about sizing the height of the container to match the height of the post. Describe this post. Post is a general term that could mean many things.

Comment: Post means a text article, It is in the middle column . The container should fill the full length of the side-bar AUTOMATICALLY.

Comment: I think I see what you are after. Edited demo.

Comment: Let me check.                                                                                               I think using a style tag for the height of the container (100%) and keeping the same in img src should solve my problem.